# Sophus Lie result on differential equations by group and Lie algebra.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Reading history of Lie group and Lie algebra, I know that Lie  did research on Lie group and Lie algebra, because He had a natural question parallel to Galois: any result about the solutions of differential equations paralell or similiar to Galois's result on algebraic equations?

My question is, has Lie gotten similiar result to Galois?

Comment: To your last question: Yes. The "Galois groups" of differential equations are Lie groups. Have a look, for example, at Majid's great book on differential Galois theory.

Comment: @DietrichBurde， thank you for the comment and the book recommended.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, you mean Magid?

Comment: Yes, Andy Magid, sorry.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Don't mind. I have been talking with his colleague this morning.